# Table name specified twice both as a target for update and separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Update table 
Set class = 0 
Where TOTAL_HOURS = (SELECT min (TOTAL_HOURS) from tutions);
```

Produced Error:

> Table name specified twice both as a target for update and separate source for data.

How can I fix this?

Comment: is that the real query ? in your query you use table as tablename and table is a keyword. so you must quote it in backticks

Answer (score 12):

I am guessing you are trying to update tutions with tutions.

Make a nested subquery so that MySQL materializes it and is no longer the same table.

Try this:

```
Update tutions
Set class = 0 
Where TOTAL_HOURS = (select * from (SELECT min (TOTAL_HOURS) from tutions) t);
```

Comment: I am sorry the Actual table is this, I was just trying to generalise for not getting others confused but I forgot to update the second one.

Comment: Update table 
Set class = 0 
Where TOTAL_HOURS = (SELECT min (TOTAL_HOURS)

Comment: @Rudra - please EDIT your question and provide the real query, what you want to do with it. Also, sample data and expected results can be more helpful